# Download URL from website with VBA macro but it doesn't have extension

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

[Browser Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pXiq.jpg)

I've been trying to find a solution but have been coming up empty handed...probably due to my own inexperience. I'm trying to automate a procedure from Excel that goes to a website (requires my username and password), downloads the Excel export file (it usually has a button next to a table that says "Export to Excel"), and saves that spreadsheet to a location on my C: drive. The problem I'm running into is that I can see the URL if I hover over the "Export to Excel" button, but it doesn't end in .CSV or .XLS. The link is websitename.com/name/# as opposed to websitename.com/name.csv. Is there a way I can find the URL for the Excel export file so that I can use that in the myURL variable from the code below?

Let me know if screenshots or anything else is helpful here. Thank you

```
Sub DownloadFile()

Dim myURL As String
myURL = "Insert URL with file extension"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "MyUserName", "MyPassword"
WinHttpReq.send

Dim oStream As Variant
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "C:\Users\Me\File.csv", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
    oStream.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. So whatever you can bring to clarify your question is welcome. Did you try the Macro Recorder?

Comment: Sometimes, depends on the webpage, even if the data comes from a CSV data, they have not been design to download, just to show. Could you give us, as I mention in my previous comment, one sample?

Comment: The "URL" you see when hovering over the button may not have any connection to how the Excel is produced or downloaded - the button may just be there to trigger a script.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my browser so you can kind of see what I'm talking about.  Can I use the macro recorder in Excel to handle this task?  Will the recorder be able to capture what I'm doing in my browser?  (Apologies in advance.  I'm still relatively new to VBA.)  Thanks!

Comment: 99% likely that is not a real working URL you're seeing but an artifact of how the menus are implemented in the browser.  You'd need to look at the HTML source to figure out what's really going on.  Macro recorder only records what you do in Excel - it will not capture actions in other applications.